# Blender Extrude Long Path Error

Tags: extrude

I'm trying to extrude long a path but I have a problem with the angles, the extruder is a simple rectangle and the path is this [image]

unfortunately this is the result

[image]

how can I solve this? how do I extrude my rectangle long to the path I provided?

Comment: Hi. Maybe this YouTube tutorial can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31rhH3FM9-c